# Maven - How to get rid of the module version in the module name?

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-dependency-plugin, maven-deploy-plugin

I have a pom for a couple of modules. When checking one of the files of this module:

```
./sources/target/build/xxxxx/xxxxx-2.13-jar-with-dependencies.jar
./compiled/target/build/xxxxx/xxxxx-2.13-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

the required result is the following (without the version):

```
xxxxx-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

I tried different ways like the `<finalName>`, `<warName>`, `<bundleFileName>`, `<outputDirectory>`, `<stripVersion>` but none of them seems to be working, the result I am getting by using most of them is:

```
./sources/target/xxxxx-jar-with-dependencies.jar
./sources/target/build/xxxxx/xxxxx-2.13-jar-with-dependencies.jar
./target/xxxxx-jar-with-dependencies.jar
./compiled/target/xxxxx-jar-with-dependencies.jar
./compiled/target/build/xxxxx/xxxxx-2.13-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

it's the result I need, but not on the files I want.

Comment: When you said you tried `finalName`, did you try the Maven Assembly one: [`<finalName>`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/single-mojo.html#finalName)? But what is it exactly you want to rename? a `jar` contained in a WAR? container in an EAR? something else entirely?

Comment: I am not 100% sure. Because I am using this module as module and as a dependency.

Comment: That's probably your problem. Could you post the POM using this module as dependency?